# what are Major triads with an added minor 6th called?

Tags: theory, chords

Im researching types of 6th chords & have not come across any site referencing such a chord. Does a Major triad with an added m6/b6 not exist?

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised I can't find this question having already been asked. Lots of minor triad with minor sixth, but not major triad with minor sixth.

Comment: @Aaron - checking over some bigband orchs, just found Cb6/9 in an arrangement of Smoke Gets in Your Eyes by Michael Philip Mossman - bars 17, 20, 25, all with different bass notes (pno parts), none of which sound to me like they're any 'C' chord. And they're not Cb 6/9, but C b6/9!

Answer (score 9):

The question should not be if it exists, of course it does. Regardless of whether or not it has much practical usage I believe the real issue here is spelling it out in a way that makes it completely clear and unambiguous.

Sometimes major chords with a b6 use the designation b13 but I advise against that because some might think a chord symbol with a 13 implies including other extensions.

Using C as an example I believe the best option is this:

C(add b6)

This indicates a C triad with one additional note, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically a maj7#5 chord (forte class 4-19B). To see it, just look at Cmaj7#5 in first inversion--it looks like E with a flat 6 added.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather unusual sounding chord. So unusual, it hardly ever gets to be played.The *minor* flat6 chord is more usually found as a major seventh version of the chord whose root is 4 semitones below that of the m♭6 chord's. And sounds good as such.

Playing a M7 chord with root right next to the M7 usually doesn't sound good - one semitone between sets up vibrations - beats - which don't help.

And it's the same with major flat 6: the P5 and ♭6 are similarly one semitone apart. There *could* be a case for calling it ♭13, but John gives good reason for not calling it that.

So, basically because it will hardly ever get used as such, why would it have a special name? And, if indeed, it does need one, C(♭6) works.

Answer (score 0):

A major triad with a minor sixth doesn't have a special name associated with it.

The presence of the minor sixth makes the chord generally too ambiguous to be used as a coloration on a major triad. More likely that ambiguity would be used in the context of a major seventh chord with a raised fifth, but in first inversion. It might be used at the end of a song in which an ambiguous finish is desirable.

Played without additional context, I hear it as the upper portion of a minor-major seventh chord with an added ninth. That chord can be found at the end of the theme song of every detective show ever.

Answer (score 0):

It exists theoretically.  C(add♭6) is a legitimate chord name.   If you like the sound, go ahead!

Answer (score -1):

Every chord exists. Any group of notes, even 2(generally called intervals) is a chord. Hell, even 1 note is a chord. A chord is a color, a sound. It represents a harmonic implication. There are many names for chords just like there are many names for paint colors. You have many types of greens and some times the same green is called by different names.

You are asking about nomenclature.

A Mm6 does exist. It's a Mm6.

Typically a very common usage is the Phrygian Dominant usage as this is the most natural context. The usage of the b6 will generally be more of a passing tone(used melodically or in extended form as a b13) although it doesn't really matter how you label it, what matters is that it sounds good and you have some way to describe the general idea.

For example, one can find such a chord on the tonic of a Mixolydian b6 scale, an Ionian b6, a Lydian b6, a Lydian Augmented(depending on precisely how you interpret the b6), etc.

It's not used much in common music because common people generally don't know how to use "complex" chords or don't like them.

Any combination of notes can be thought of as a chord. If you think of chords like this and that they are just colors then things will make more sense. The naming scheme of chords is just to communicate with words what one hears in sounds. Just like the word BOOM is to communicate an aural thing and red is to communicate a visual thing. Don't expect nomenclature to be complete though. Music notation is the notation used to precisely, well mostly, communicate musical sound.

The simplest way to state a Mm6 chord is a Mm6 chord. Or you could use something like Mb6. Generally these chords are known as b13 chords and are quite common in more advanced music(more advanced than pop and childrens songs). b13 major chords usually have some additional extensions to fill in the sound but music is context dependent. Learn the nomenclature as just a way to name things and don't confuse naming with the actual music.

Comment: Calling it a Lydian augmented chord is wrong, because of the perfect fifth in the major triad. In a Lydian augmented chord you don't have a perfect fifth.

Comment: It has a b6 which is enharmonic to a #5. The n5 could be non-harmonic. Everything depends on it's usage, context, and emphasis. There is only one chord in 12-tet and that is the chromatic 12-note chord.

Comment: OP says there is a major triad. In a Lydian augmented chord the fourth is raised, otherwise it wouldn't be Lydian, and the fifth is raised or otherwise it wouldn't be an augmented chord. There is no way to explain this so that a Lydian augmented chord would have a perfect fifth.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Wrong, it depends context. If he means out of context then yes, you can't have a major triad be an augmented triad else you would just say augmented triad. But in context, and what really matters, the p5 may not be the actual 5 of the chord that is dominants the sonority. For example, the P5 may actually be a pedal tone or suspension and actually not part harmony but which may look to be on paper. If one is not aware that context they will blindly try to apply the nomenclature and forever be confused by what actually happens in practice.